# Unable to select date in month_view in android date picker in detox

Tags: android, detox

Writing ui automation tests using detox.  The following date picker view is being used for android.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfHDi.png)

I can select the current date by selecting the "OK" button, but I don't seem to be able to select a specific value in the month_view.  Research on interacting with android calendar pickers has not born any fruit, so looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: I have looked more into the issue. The DatePicker component being used is the react native community date time picker found at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/datetimepicker. Having read the documentation, I do not see how to expose the values of the dates in the android date picker view. Hence when I view the calendar using Android Studio layout inspector tool, the values of each day are not exposed as text.  Has anyone any experience of how to do this?

Comment: Hi @TopLuddite, did you manage to resolve the issue? If yes, would you mind sharing the solution?

Answer (score 1):

@TopLuddite I can advise on 2 things:

1. As a first step, try to inspect the layout when the date picker shows (*), using Android Studio's `Layout Inspector` tool (under the `Tools` menu). In the captured layout, look up values in `methods > getTag()` associated with the views you wish to tap on. These are equivalent to what Detox sees as test-IDs, which means that if the value is not null, it is applicable for usage in Detox' [`by.id(<value>)`](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.Matchers.md#byidid) view-matching API. That's one straightforward way to solve your issue.
2. As an alternative, consider using Android's `UIAutomator` (`UIDevice`) API, available via Detox using the [`device.getUiDevice()`](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.DeviceObjectAPI.md#devicegetuidevice-android-only) call. In particular, API's such as [`UiDevice.pressDPadDown`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiDevice#pressdpaddown()) can come in handy, or, as a last resort - [`UiDevice.click(x, y)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiDevice#click(int,%20int)).

---

(*) Note: you must run the app in Debug mode for that to work.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @d4vidi.  Re 1. I have made use of the layout inspector, but unfortunately when you select a date in the date picker view, these do not register at all layout inspector.   Re 2. - I had not heard of that before, and I will investigate that.  I am hoping I do not have to resort to UIDevice.click(x, y), as that seems likely to create test maintenance issue.

Comment: Keep us posted!